# При повороте экрана из Pageview исчезают page

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, adapter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Pageview находиться в Fragmente

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pts_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    pagerAdapter = new AdapterPageSearch(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: делал все по урокам http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html

Answer (score -1):

Заменил `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`
на `getChildFragmentManager()`,
и все заработало